# Mejorar método de búsqueda SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen día.

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una base de datos en la cual se almacena la información de personal de una empresa, específicamente tengo una tabla en la cual se guarda en campos separados el nombre de la persona (Paterno, Materno, Nombre) entre otros datos, necesito implementar una búsqueda a dicha tabla, sin embargo no me funciona del todo, este es mi procedimiento almacenado que utilizo actualmente en el cuál concateno los tres campos como un todo para buscar

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Catalogos_BuscaPersona]
@nombre as varchar(300)
AS
BEGIN
select @nombre = replace(@nombre,' ','')
select top 50 
   cu.Paterno, cu.Materno, cu.Nombre from 
   Tbl_Personal cu
   where 
   (
(
    @nombre = '' or 
    upper(replace(Nombre,' ','') +replace(Paterno,' ','') + replace(Materno,' ','')) like '%'+upper(@nombre)+'%'
)   
   )
END
```

Dicho procedimiento recibe una cadena con el nombre completo desde un solo text box por ejemplo; si pongo que me busque la cadena `'yolanda garcia'` me regresa el resultado esperado, sin embargo si el usuario lo teclea a la inversa `'garcia yolanda'`, ya no regresa resultado alguno supongo es por el orden en el cúal se define la concatenación de los campos, pero me gustaría que me regrese resultados sin importar el orden en que reciba la información ya sea que reciba ('nombre' + 'paterno') o ('nombre'+ 'materno') o ('nombre' + 'paterno' + 'materno') o ('paterno' + 'nombre') etc.

Alguien ha hecho algo por el estilo? o sabe de alguna solución?

Muchas gracias por su atención

Comment: Averigua sobre arboles invertidos y otras formas de busqueda. en una base de datos relacional no vas a poder solucionar esto con un query simple.

Comment: Tal como lo planteas parece simple, con invertir las palabras en la búsqueda y probar las dos combinaciones sería suficiente.  Es decir  `dato like `%'yolanda garcia%' or  dato like `%'garcia yolanda%'`. Pero ¿Realmente eso te sirve? ¿Que pasa cuando se debe buscar por más de dos palabras? ¿Que pasa si el usuario separa las palabras con comas u otro signo? ¿Que ocurre si de tres palabras solo coinciden dos? Te pregunto estas cosas por que hay una línea que separa una búsqueda estándar, de un búsqueda difusa o el uso del `FULL TEXT INDEX` del Sql server

Comment: Pero el FULL TEXT INDEX técnicamente solo me resolvería en cuestión de performance no es así? según vi documentación es adecuado para el manejo de datos donde se tiene cadenas de texto muy largas o me equivoco?

Comment: No, no es solo una cuestión de performance, el `FULL TEXT INDEX` permite usar algunas clausulas interesantes `CONTAINS` o `FREETEXT` que tal vez te ayuden, revisa esto: http://www.mug-it.org.ar/332351-Usando-Full-Text-Index.note.aspx. Pero de todas formas, si tu necesidad es más concreta como ser buscar múltiples palabras en cadenas de texto sin importar el orden, se podría resolver con una consulta más o menos simple, seguramente no demasiado performante. ¿Que versión de SQL Server tienes?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2014 standart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si entendí bien, lo que buscas es: *Encontrar coincidencias en tres columnas de una tabla con un cadena ingresada por el usuario que contiene múltiples palabras separadas por espacios, el orden no debe ser determinante, es decir `yolanda garcia` debería coincidir con `garcia yolanda`*

Esto podría ser eventualmente resuelto con un `LIKE` que buscara por las dos combinaciones la original y la invertida (deberíamos encargarnos antes de invertir lo ingresado por el usuario), esto funcionaría bien para el caso que se ingresen dos palabras, pero ¿si ingresan más? y además ¿Qué ocurre si el usuario usa más de un espacio para separar las palabras?.

Esta alternativa es un poco más flexible y funcional, pero no necesariamente performante, esto último deberás evaluarlo. Conceptualmente lo que vamos a hacer es "construir" una tabla de palabras con la "frase" que hubiera ingresado el usuario, luego buscar las coincidencias individuales de cada palabra, y por último "pesar" la cantidad de coincidencias en cada columna para obtener las "mejores" filas.

En primer lugar, creamos una tabla de ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Tbl_Personal (
    Nombre  VARCHAR(1000),
    Materno VARCHAR(1000),
    Paterno VARCHAR(1000)
)
    
INSERT INTO Tbl_Personal (Nombre, Materno, Paterno)
VALUES  ('Luis Ortigoza', 'Marcela Morello', 'Juan manuel Funes'),
    ('Ernesto Guevara', 'Sandra Bullock', 'Luis Gilberto Enrique'),
    ('Juan Gilberto Funes', 'Natalie Portman', 'Samuel Fuller'),
    ('Juan maria Volonte', 'Gena Davies', 'Morgan Freeman')
```

Ahora bien, supongamos que el usuario hubiera ingresado el texto **`Funes  Gilberto Juan`**, nota que hay varios espacios entre algunas de las palabras. Para transformar esta "frase" en una tabla con los valores de cada palabra, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @NombreBuscar   VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT  @NombreBuscar   =  'Funes  Gilberto Juan'

-- Armamos Tabla de palabras a buscar
DECLARE @Palabras  TABLE (
    String  VARCHAR(1000),
    NR  INT
)

INSERT INTO @Palabras (String, NR)
SELECT  String,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.String) AS 'NR' 
    FROM (SELECT    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS String
            FROM  (SELECT   CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Nombre], ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
                         FROM  (SELECT @NombreBuscar AS 'Nombre') TableA
                ) AS A 
            CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
    ) A
    WHERE LEN(RTRIM(A.String)) > 0
```

La salida de esta tabla sería algo así:

```
+----------+------+
| Funes    | 1.00 |
+----------+------+
| Gilberto | 2.00 |
+----------+------+
| Juan     | 3.00 |
+----------+------+
```

Y ahora traslademos esto a la consulta de la tabla `Tbl_Personal`

```
SELECT  T.Nombre, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT P1.NR) AS 'CoincidenciasNombre',
    T.Materno, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT P2.NR) AS 'CoincidenciasMaterno',
    T.Paterno, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT P3.NR) AS 'CoincidenciasPaterno'
    FROM Tbl_Personal T
    LEFT JOIN @Palabras P1
        ON ' ' + T.Nombre + ' ' LIKE '% ' + P1.String + ' %'
    LEFT JOIN @Palabras P2
        ON ' ' + T.Materno + ' ' LIKE '% ' + P2.String + ' %'
    LEFT JOIN @Palabras P3
        ON ' ' + T.Paterno + ' ' LIKE '% ' + P3.String + ' %'
    WHERE   P1.String IS NOT NULL
        OR P2.String IS NOT NULL
        OR P3.String IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        T.Nombre,
        T.Materno,
        T.Paterno
```

La salida final sería algo así:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Nombre              | CoincidenciasNombre | Materno         | CoincidenciasMaterno | Paterno               | CoincidenciasPaterno |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Ernesto Guevara     | 0,00                | Sandra Bullock  | 0,00                 | Luis Gilberto Enrique | 1,00                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Juan Gilberto Funes | 3,00                | Natalie Portman | 0,00                 | Samuel Fuller         | 0,00                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Juan maria Volonte  | 1,00                | Gena Davies     | 0,00                 | Morgan Freeman        | 0,00                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| Luis Ortigoza       | 0,00                | Marcela Morello | 0,00                 | Juan manuel Funes     | 2,00                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

Esta salida te da por columna la cantidad de palabras que coinciden con la misma. Esto te puede dar flexibildad para ordenar los resultados por relevancia y ofrecer varias alternativas, sino simplemente hay que filtrar aquellos registros dónde la cantidad de coincidencias en cualquier columna tengan la misma cantidad de palabras buscadas.

Nota:

Hacer esto:

```
LEFT JOIN @Palabras P1
            ON ' ' + T.Nombre + ' ' LIKE '% ' + P1.String + ' %'
```

Puede parecer extraño, básicamente de esta forma nos aseguramos buscar por palabra, si quitásemos todos los espacios se darían coincidencias seguramente no deseadas como `Juan == Juanes`

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5d4a68eefcdaff923700d1652a26dad7)

Comment: +1 por el buen detalle explicativo :)

Comment: gracias @J.Rodríguez, saludos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, gracias por la ayuda al parecer si se acerca bastante a lo que buscaba

Comment: Justo lo que yo buscaba tambien